# Is the 2,500 request limit for the "Directions Web Service" IP based?

Tags: google-maps

I'm developing an application that uses the "Directions Web Service."  The documents state that the free version of the API is limited to 2,500 requests per day.  (See http://maps.google.com/help/maps/getmaps/compare.html).

In our application this request is made in javascript on the clients browser, it's not done by our server.  So I'm wondering if this limit is per user IP address or somehow it's going to pass along my applications URL/IP and limit based on that.

Any ideas?

Comment: You answered it yourself - it is done client side so it would be based on the clients IP.

Answer (score 4):

Using the [Google Maps API v3 Directions Service in the Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) the request limitations and quotas apply per client (IP Address).

Using the [Directions Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) the request limitations and quotas apply to the server (to its IP Address).

I will admit that the link you provided doesn't make it very clear which one they are talking about.

Comment: I don't understand - if I deploy an Android app that uses directions api, will it only make 2500 requests per 24 hours, or is it per device??